# How to call .phtml file for email template?

Tags: magento2, order-email

I'm designing template from

> "Magento_Sales/templates/email/order_update/statusinfo_guest.phtml"

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

{{trans "%order_status" order_status=$order.getFrontendStatusLabel() |raw}}

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

and i called in backend like

```
 {{block class='Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\Template' area='frontend' template='Magento_Sales::email/order_update/statusinfo_guest.phtml'  order=$order}}
```

When i change sales order status i'm getting email  like 
[image]

What i do wrong? Please let me know

Answer (score 3):

you can call .phtml for email template by doing this:
first you have to load .phtml file into html file with following script

```
{{block class='Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\Template' area='adminhtml' template='Vendor_Modulename::email/xyz.phtml'}}
```

**Note**: Please don't forget to pass correct file path inside template(template='Vendor_Modulename::email/xyz.phtml').

Comment: i used a correct file path, so only i'm getting email like same as in my .phtml file.

Comment: @mohana Ok then it might be other issue.

Answer (score 0):

etc/email_templates.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../Email/etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="statusinfo_guest" label="Email Form" file="statusinfo_guest.html" type="html" module="Vendor_Module" area="frontend"/>

</config>
```

write this code in

view/frontend/email/statusinfo_guest.html

Note: remember file type is "html"

```
    {{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

    {{trans "%order_status" order_status=$order.getFrontendStatusLabel() |raw}}

    {{layout handle="email_sample_layout" order=$order area="frontend"}}

    {{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

now add layout file "email_sample_layout.xml" in view/frontend/layout and add below code in it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Product List" design_abstraction="custom">

    <body>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="status_info" template="Magento_Sales::email/order_update/statusinfo_guest.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now write what you want to show in your phtml file "statusinfo_guest.phtml"

Hope it works.

Comment: No, it's not working again i'm getting same "http://prntscr.com/oc3ul6"

Comment: could you please share the screenshot of your template file

Comment: Actually i like to use more content, but i tested for with few sample http://prntscr.com/oc3zar

Comment: actually, you are writing code in the wrong file, see my updated answer

Comment: "view/frontend/email/statusinfo_guest.html" or else "view/frontend/email/order_update/statusinfo_guest.html"

Comment: you had call "order_update/statusinfo_guest.html" in .xml file?

Comment: as you wish but don't forget to update the file path in email_templates.xml in etc

Comment: yes   i called in etc/email_templates.xml

Comment: we can't use in layout/email_templates.xml ?

Comment: see my update answer

Comment: Okay , let me know once i check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95899/discussion-between-mohana-and-abdus).